# Variable declared but doesn't show up during Debug C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-debugging

screenshot of debug: http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/12/36121481470-orig.jpg

note how x, y have values (i have no idea why x and y stopped on 69 in the for loop - x should've went up to 86 and y to 183) yet r has no value at all. (the variable doesn't exist? what?) how should I fix this?

code if you want to read:

```
        public float[] cht(int[,] matrix)
    {
        float[] xyrd = new float[4];
        int xthreshold, ythreshold;
        float slope;
        double dir;
        float zone;
        int[] limitsStorage = new int[3] { matrix.GetLength(0), matrix.GetLength(1), matrix.GetLength(0) / 2 - 10 };
        short[,,] accumulator = new short[limitsStorage[0]+1, limitsStorage[1]+1,limitsStorage[2]+1];
        for (int x = 0; x < limitsStorage[0]; x++)
        { //first dimension loop of matrix 100
            for (int y = 0; y < limitsStorage[1]; y++)
            { //second dimension loop of matrix 120
                if (matrix[x, y] == 225)
                {//the data at the for loop location is a 1 and not 0 hit.
                    xthreshold = x - limitsStorage[0] / 2;
                    ythreshold = y - limitsStorage[1] / 2;
                    //forget angle, search slope: float angle = xthreshold > 0 ? ((float)Math.Atan2(xthreshold, ythreshold)) : ((float)Math.Atan2(xthreshold, ythreshold) + 180);
                    slope = xthreshold / ythreshold;
                    //initiate if loops.
                    dir = 180 + Math.Round(Math.Atan2(ythreshold, xthreshold) * 57.2957 / 45, 0) * 45 + 45 * (Math.Round(((Math.Atan2(ythreshold, xthreshold) * 57.2957) % 45) / 45));
                    if (slope > .404 || slope < -.404)
                    {
                        if (slope < 2.3558 || slope > -2.3558)
                        {
                            if (xthreshold > 0)
                            {
                                if (ythreshold > 0)
                                {
                                    //+x+y zone
                                    zone = 45 + 180;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //+x-y zone
                                    zone = 180 - 45;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (ythreshold > 0)
                                {
                                    //-x+y zone
                                    zone = 360 - 45;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //-x-y zone
                                    zone = 45;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (ythreshold > 0)
                        {
                            //+y zone
                            zone = 360 - 90;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //-y zone
                            zone = 90;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (xthreshold > 0)
                    {
                        //+x zone
                        zone = 180;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //-x zone
                        zone = 0;
                    }
                    for (int R = 6; R < limitsStorage[2]; R++)
                    { //Radius loop for scan 44
                        float delta = (float)((1 / R) * 57.2957);
                        for (float Theta = zone - 25; Theta < zone + 25; Theta += delta)
                        {
                            accumulator[(int)(((R * Math.Cos(Theta / 57.2957)) < 0 || (R * Math.Cos(Theta / 57.2957)) > limitsStorage[0]) ? 0 : R * Math.Cos(Theta / 57.2957)), (int)(((R * Math.Sin(Theta / 57.2957)) < 0 || (R * Math.Sin(Theta / 57.2957)) > limitsStorage[1]) ? 0 : R * Math.Sin(Theta / 57.2957)),R]++;
                            //btw, 0,0,R is always the non-center area.
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 1; x < limitsStorage[0]; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y < limitsStorage[1]; y++)
            {
                for (int r = 6; r < limitsStorage[2]; r++)
                {
                    if (xyrd[3] > accumulator[x, y, r])
                    {
                        xyrd[0] = x;
                        xyrd[1] = y;
                        xyrd[2] = r;
                        xyrd[3] = accumulator[x, y, r];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (accPrint)
        {
            //do something for debugging?
            accPrint = false;
        }
        return xyrd;
    }
```

Comment: Optimized away, perhaps?

Comment: "weird behaviour" does not constitute a question. It is neither helpful or descriptive. Also, the code you posted is somewhat horrible...

Comment: "weird-behaviour" was not presented as a question. It was presented as the one and only tag, which was equally inappropriate.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: "somewhat horrible" is too somewhat kind.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: I was referring to the overall sentiment of the question rather than the explicit tag.

Comment: ehh ^^; sorry guys, still rather newb to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that the `x` and `y` have the little lock symbol under them indicating that you have private variables named `x` and `y` in the class in which this method is executing. Those are the `x` and `y` that you are seeing in the debugger.

`r` is appropriately out of scope as you've exited the loop in which it is declared.

By the way, `x` and `y` are ridiculously bad member variable names, and are ridiculously bad names for `for` loop variables of type `int`, especially if they are contained in a class with member variables named `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

The only place you declare `r` is in the `for` statement, right? That means `r` goes out of scope as soon as the loop ends. So naturally if you inspect variables at he end of the function, `r` won't be there.

Confessing I don't know why `x` and `y` are in scope based on the comments. They could be class variables, but the asker says not. That's the only explanation I can think of, though.

Comment: @kindall: In general I'd agree with you but note that `x` and `y` are still "visible" and the same reasoning applies to both `x` and `y`.

Comment: @kindall: That would not be legal C#. A local variable cannot be declared in a scope where there is a variable with the same name in the current or a parent scope.

Comment: @kindall: i checked, there's no random floating x and y globals... this function is directly under a timer_tick event

Comment: @Jason: That's not entirely true; a class variable can be hidden by a variable defined in a method.

Comment: @kindall: Please see this post and you'll understand the distinction: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is not weird -- you actually get exactly what you expect.

Please note that the watch window can only accurately show you values that are ***in scope*** at the breakpoint.

At the highlighted breakpoint, only accumulator[x, y, r] is in scope, and you see exactly the values you expected.

Comment: You're seeing x and y because you declared them above, in a previous loop. Those values do not reflect the second loop, if you did not break within it. You don't see `r` because in the first loop you declared it as `R` -- capitalized.

Comment: @Jay: That is complete nonsense.

Comment: @Jason, no it isn't. If you break within one `for` loop, the watch window will show the exit value for that variable even after it goes out of scope.

Comment: @Jay: It's grayed out in that case and if you hover over it, the debugger will tell you that the value is stale and there will be a little refresh button in the "Value" column which, when you hover over, will tell you that the variable is not available in the current context. That's not the case here.

Comment: @Jay: that's coincidence, i merely changed the latter R to r because i wanted to see if it's messed up because I had declared the variable before.

Comment: Well, there must be a class-level variable there -- the `x` and `y` icons have a lock symbol -- private class variables.

Comment: @Jay: Yup, I noticed that too.